# Access Parse Cloud Code results

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

```
IDictionary<string, object> test2 = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "username", ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username}
            };

        var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<Object>("getShiftCount", test2);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(result);
```

I retrieve an array of boolean values using Parse Cloud Code. I'm new to C# so I assume that the array gets assigned to `result`. But how can I access the individual elements of the array?

Right now I just get `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]`

Comment: Not familiar with the library you are calling so I don't know the types, but you can use the foreach construct like this:  foreach (FooShiftCount element in result) { element.CallSomeMethod(); }

Comment: Googling the question gives a 100% match at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as the first result. See chapter "Accessing Array Members". Please do a minimum of research by yourself.

Comment: Based of the answer below, accessing it with results[2] does not work

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, then please do not modify the question to get your next problem fixed. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: My problem was not solved

Comment: @nick9999: you wanted to access an element of the array. The answer states how to do that: `var element = result[elementIndex];`

Comment: I think @Mati Cicero is suggesting you change your call so that instead of type <Object> you refer to <List<object>>... did you do that before trying to access it with result[2] ?

Comment: @nick9999 Updated my answer to reflect your expected type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<T>` is a generic method.

According to [Parse Documentation](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/M_Parse_ParseCloud_CallFunctionAsync__1_1.htm), `T` is the type of data you will receive from your cloud function.

That is, if your `getShiftCount` returns a `List<object>`, then you should reformulate your function call to this:

```
var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<List<object>>("getShiftCount", test2);
```

Then, you would be able to obtain any individual element using an index:

```
int elementIndex = 2;
var element = result[elementIndex];
```

Comment: @nick9999 For the record, don't copy and paste my sample code, I don't know what exact type you expect from your cloud function. Instead, try to understand what the function does and try to fix it by your own. If that fails, I'm always here to help

Comment: "object" needs to be "Object" but other than that it worked. Thanks!